# Test the convergence of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^q}$$
Show that the series is convergent for $q \gt 1$ and divergent for $q \le 1$.

So my attempt started with doing it for $q = 1$:
$$\frac{\log(n)}{n} \gt \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\sum\frac{\log(n)}{n} \gt \sum\frac{1}{n}$$
since RHS is divergent therfore LHS is divergent

now for $q \lt 1$ :
$$ \frac{\log(n)}{n^q} \gt \frac{\log(n)}{n}$$
$$ \sum\frac{\log(n)}{n^q} \gt \sum\frac{\log(n)}{n}$$
since RHS is divergent as proved above therefore LHS is divergent

**Now I don’t get how to do for $\,q>1.$**

Comment: You must provide us your attempt(s) to solve the problem yourself, questions "do my homework for me" style are poorly received on Stack Exchange sites in general

Comment: oh ok wait i will add

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg Done

Comment: Hint: If $q=1+2s$, then $$\frac{\log n}{n^q} = \frac{\log n}{n^s} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{1+s}}$$

Comment: @aschepler Sorry I don't follow along

Comment: Then look at the duplicate

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry i don't understand how the comparison test is helping me here, I also tried applying Raabe test but i got some complicated limits though when I solved them using calculator i got my answer, I just wanted some simple way for q>1 like i had for others

Comment: Hint: Show for any $\epsilon>0$ that  $\frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}}\to 0.$ Then, if $q>1$ let $\epsilon=\frac{q-1}2.$

Comment: OK Finally figured it out after a bit of research on the duplicate question, thankyou for help

Comment: As the question was well edited I retracted my downvote.

Comment: This is the [link](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html) which I referred.